Align currency symbol of a textField to the left and amount to the right
I'm trying to have the following format in a table cell's textField which is set as a single String.

I tried like the below with tab charater with html markup format. But the $ symbol is not aligning as the number of digits differ. I want it aligned on same position.
"$&#09;"+ amountStr; // amountStr contains 869,965.00


